# Do observational astronomers make use of the Fredholm equation? Perhaps in solving for/removing instrumental effects in imaging?

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, photography, image-processing

The Fredholm equation of the first kind ([Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FredholmIntegralEquationoftheFirstKind.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation#Equation_of_the_first_kind)) written as (Wolfram's):

> $$f(x) = \int_a^b K(x, t) \ \phi(t) \ dt$$
>
> where $K(x, t)$ is the kernel and $\phi(t)$ is an unknown function to be solved for (Arfken 1985, p. 865).
>
> If the kernel is of the special form $K(x - t)$ and the limits are infinite so that the equation becomes
>
> $$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x - t) \ \phi(t) \ dt$$
>
> then the solution (assuming the relevant transforms exist) is given by
>
> $$\phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{F_x[f(x)](k)}{F_x[K(x)](k)} \ \exp(2 i \pi k x) \ dk$$
>
> where $F_x$ is the Fourier transforms operator (Arfken 1985, pp. 875 and 877).

This I can understand; the Fourier transform of a convolution of two functions is just the product of their Fourier transforms. The $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(2 i \pi k x) \ dk$ is just the inverse Fourier transform, and the fraction comes from moving the Fourier transform of the kernel $K$ from one side to the other.

To me this looks like it could be a way to solve for the un-diffracted image of a galaxy $\phi$ starting with the diffracted image $f$ and say an Airy function kernel $K$.

I suppose an array of radio telescope dishes would have a more complicated kernel.

While observational astronomers might under some conditions remove instrumental effects by de-convoluting an image before analysis or fitting something to it, **the alternative would be to *convolute the model with the kernel* and fit that to the raw data instead.**

**Question:** Do observational astronomers make use of the Fredholm equation? Perhaps in solving for/removing instrumental effects in imaging?

Comment: Have you considered noise in the image...? BTW Convoluting the model with the point spread function and matching to the observations is the standard way to do this

Comment: @ProfRob only in the last sixty seconds :-) My limited experience in this area isn't enough to tell me if deconvoluting the data is better or worse than convoluting the model because I only fit smooth functions. But Oh! you guys have stars, both real and spurious. Yikes!

Comment: @ProfRob but note that I've also discussed radio astronomy where the data is smoother and the noise not as pixelated.